# How to animate falling feathers?

Tags: animation, rigging, workflow

I think that [this animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hs8aqnYpJMY) is possible in blender with a rig, yes?

Rig or is there another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also try a *Curve* modifier, if you want a fixed path, and there is no need for physics or interaction with any other objects.

Have in mind that it may lead to undesirable deformation at tight corners.

[image: Feather Bezier Curve]