# Blender Cycles How to make paper that will move like is rigged?

Tags: animation

I for a project am making a paper and wind to fly into the air and through clouds. How can I animated the paper to look like it is flying in the wind? I also want to put picture?

Comment: Maybe look into the cloth simulator: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/cloth/index.html

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68549/how-to-animate-falling-feathers