# Intertwined snakes animation

Tags: animation

I'm trying to create an animation of two intertwined snakes. I would like to animate the snake first raising from the floor, then backing a little bit to take impulse and then follow a circular motion while intertwining with its mate.

So far I have used a curve for the snake to follow while reaching a stand position,the problem is animating the backing and intertwine following different curves.

Is there any way to assign different curves in different keys? Is there a better way to achieve this effect than following paths? I would like it to be as physically accurate as possible, I have tried mixing the curve with physics like cloth or softbody, although softbody might get a nice effect it is not yet what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68549/how-to-animate-falling-feathers

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos that is exactly what I have used so far, but I can't use just one curve since the movement implies different curves at different stages of the animation.