# How to make a floating feather?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I wanted to ask you how would you make a feather softly falling to the ground. Cloth simulation? Manually? I need help. So grateful!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68549/how-to-animate-falling-feathers

Comment: wow thank u so much! that will work!

Answer (score 2):

well...of course you can do it with physics, but of course it is a lot of try and error...that's what i did :)

i made this geometry

[image]

then added subdiv modifier and cloth:

[image]

and a bit of wind with some random rotations and some noise modifier on the strength and i got this:

[image]

[image]

i know...it is not falling, but i think it has a nice movement ;)

[image]